# Visual Studio 2017 Show Table Data does not work

Tags: database, visual-studio, server-explorer

I am using Visual Studio 2017's 'Server Explorer' to connect to a Microsoft SQL database. I set up the connection and successfully connect to the database and can see the tables. However when I choose the 'Show Table Data' from one of the tables, I get the error 'An unexpected error occurred while populating the table or view information.'

Interestingly, if I execute the query: 'SELECT * from table' for the same table, this seems to work correctly and shows the table data.

Note also, that if I use Visual Studio 2010, I can connect to this same database and everything works as expected.

Does anyone have an idea why this does not work in the 2017 version?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check the additional info I posted and see if it's the same issue.

Comment: I suppose it could be, but how are you seeing the sql request that is generated? When I run the command I just get the error message, no sql window opens and I cannot see the request that was made.

Comment: I'm getting the sql text in the error pop up.

Comment: I do not. see that. I get a simple popup message box which contains only the information I specified above.

Comment: Rollback.  It looks like my issue should be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting the connection and adding it again. No need for restarting.
I use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019.